# .Net WebApi how to know if config is being used

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, asp.net-web-api

## Background

I have a situation where the default way that .Net WebApi projects work isn't working for my team. We spawn off a new "version" of our code every few weeks. For example, we might build a site for Company A that has more or less the same back end code, with the exception of connection strings. Most of the client code will be the same, but some will be custom and the index.cshtml will be custom.

As a first step to creating a clean delineation so the shared code can go into its own repositories and the custom front end code can go to one repo per client, I am splitting the front end out into its own project and stripping down the project that previously was the WebApi and the client side code to only contain the WebApi code and nothing unnecessary. To do this, I started from an Empty project with the WebApi check box checked and started adding things back until the project would at least compile.

Even if we weren't still using VS 2013 and .Net 4.5, I feel like a gulp-based solution isn't right for us right now (and I researched this for over a week, so **please** keep this in mind while answering).

The problem I'm having is I think that the HTTPConfiguration I'm building isn't being used by the app. The symptoms are it doesn't seem to be recognizing the most custom route definition and I don't think it's using the JSON Contract resolver.

I tried installing the RouteDebugger, but it seems to be depending on older versions of some Nuget packages, so it won't install.

## Code

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureOAuth(app);

            var config = new HttpConfiguration();

            var container = new Container();
            container.RegisterSingle();
            config.DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.UseWebApi(config);

            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            config.EnsureInitialized();
        }
    }
```

```
   public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static string UrlPrefix { get { return "";  } }
        public static string UrlPrefixRelative { get { return ""; } }

        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.EnableCors();

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
              name: "SignOnApi",
              routeTemplate: UrlPrefix + "{controller}/{language}",
              defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "SessionRoute",
                routeTemplate: UrlPrefix + "{controller}/{action}/{userId}",
                defaults: new {userId = RouteParameter.Optional}
                );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: UrlPrefix + "{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType().First();
            jsonFormatter.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = true;
            jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        }
    }
```

I have verified that all this code does in fact execute.

## The Question(s)

- Since I can't install the RouteDebugger, is there another way I can verify my HTTPConfiguration is being used?
- Is there something in the information I've given (above or below) that points to a different explanation of what the issue is?

Please let me know if there's additional information I missed--this is already a long question.

## Errors

When I call one service that uses a get method from the browser, I get

```
<Error><Message>An error has occurred.</Message><ExceptionMessage>Type 'VJTNext.Models.Templates.SituationalJudgement' with data contract name 'SituationalJudgement:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/VJTNext.Models.Templates' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.</ExceptionMessage><ExceptionType>System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException</ExceptionType><StackTrace>   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at WriteArrayOfanyTypeToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at WriteTemplateSectionToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at WriteArrayOfTemplateSectionToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at WriteTemplateMasterToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.WriteObject(XmlWriter writer, Object graph)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Web.Http.Owin.HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.<BufferResponseContentAsync>d__13.MoveNext()</StackTrace></Error>
```

I get that it may not be using the JSON resolver because I'm calling it directly from the browser, but my understanding is the XML resolver should be equally forgiving.

When the AngularJS client calls a post method on a different service, it gets back

```
"<Error>No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http:\/\/localhost:58324\/api
\/Account\/RegisterUser'.<\/Message><MessageDetail>No action was found on the controller 'Account' that
 matches the request.<\/MessageDetail><\/Error>"
```

## Update

When I split the project, I set up the Web Api part to run in a virtual subdirectory of the client-side code (to be published to a physical subdirectory on the real server). The controller that was doing *something* but not using the data contract had no RoutePrefix metadata, but the others did. So, removing "api/" from the prefix fixed it, because these services are now actually in that directory instead of notionally at that path.

So now it's down to getting the data contract working.

Comment: Where do you populate this static prefixes? Looks like somewhere this are getting overrided. Another thing that I notice, this prefixes will keep the same until the Pool restarts.

Comment: The prefixes are just empty at this point, because of the split. Originally, it was "/api" or "~/api" based on how we were deploying.

Comment: Have you tried to put your UseWebApi(config) call after your call to .Register(config)?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it both ways.

Comment: This Register method will be called only one time, and will be unchanged until the pool refresh. Maybe thats your issue. You can't change the route dynamically at executions time. If you need that you should consider to implemente a custom RouteProvider

Comment: Please review the "Update" section just above these comments.

Comment: Why you didn't use Route attribute?

Comment: @dan, are you talking about the metadata that I said I changed in the Update, or some other thing?